# What is the possible value for the Concatenated String for generating SAML Signature

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, onelogin

```
>   <samlp:LogoutRequest ID="_36167d94-d868-4c04-aee3-8bbd4ed91317"
> Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2017-01-05T16:21:55.704Z"
> Destination="https://werain.me/"
> xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer
> xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline</Issuer><NameID
> Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
> xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">4948f6ce-4e3b-4538-b284-1461f9379b48</NameID><samlp:SessionIndex>_eafbb730-b590-0134-a918-00d202739c81</samlp:SessionIndex></samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

Given my, Logout Request looks like this. If I have to verify the Logout request do I have to construct the string that looks like this (i.e raw string value)

```
SAMLRequest=<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="_36167d94-d868-4c04-aee3-8bbd4ed91317" ... </samlp:LogoutRequest>&SigAlg=http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1
```

and then verify the signature for the above string or should I `encode` the `SAMLRequest` and `SigAlg` value

i.e

```
SAMLRequest=Base64 encode value or raw logout request&SigAlg=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2F09%2Fxmldsig%23rsa-sha1
```

Reason for this confusion is 
SAML spec says extracted from [here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/Post2.0/sstc-saml-binding-simplesign-cd-04.html)

> A string consisting of the concatenation of the raw, unencoded XML
>   making up the SAML protocol message (NOT the base64-encoded version),

But OneSAML Create a signature with the Base64 encode version of the request (logout request). Have a look at [here](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/blob/20489a041069864e65d03a196d816406a89db28b/lib/onelogin/ruby-saml/logoutrequest.rb#L66)

Not sure what is the correct implementation I have to use to verify the signature.

**NOTE: HTTP-Redirect BINDING.**

Answer (score 0):

Your link and quote is not related with the HTTP-Redirect binding.

Check the 3.4.4.1 section of
https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-bindings-2.0-os.pdf

Onelogin's SAML toolkits implement signatures following the standard.

You can see for example that the implementation of simpleSAMLphp build the signature on the Redirect binding on the same way:
https://github.com/simplesamlphp/saml2/blob/master/src/SAML2/HTTPRedirect.php#L22

Or opensaml
https://github.com/apigee/java-opensaml2/blob/master/src/main/java/org/opensaml/saml2/binding/encoding/HTTPRedirectDeflateEncoder.java#L162

You can play signing and validating SAML Messages with:
https://www.samltool.com/online_tools.php